# Import data from JSON file into table with collapsed rows in Angular 6

Tags: angular, html-table, angular6

I started to learn angular 6 and I am really in the beginning.
I need to create this kind of table:

[image]

It should show information about computers related to websites AD in different areas of different countries.

Data file is JSON and looks like:

```
 {"countryList":[{"Country":null,"Area":null,"AD_Site_Name":null,"Netbios_Name":null,"UserName":"ABILITY\\gaynullin_mf","ARPProductName":"WinRAR 5.31 (64-разрядная)","FilePath":"C:\\Program Files\\WinRAR\\","InstalledSource":"Other","LastHWScan":"2018-05-26T12:56:41","LastScanDate":"2018-05-26T02:57:25"},
 {"Country":null,"Area":null,"AD_Site_Name":null,"Netbios_Name":null,"UserName":"ABILITY\\ufa_it","ARPProductName":"WinRAR 4.01 (64-разрядная)","FilePath":"C:\\Program Files\\WinRAR\\","InstalledSource":"Other","LastHWScan":"2018-05-24T15:02:41","LastScanDate":"2018-05-24T19:28:05"}]}
```

I have imported data from JSON file to a simple table, but I need to create collapsed rows. So firstly there should be list of countries, then user should click on it and there will be list of areas, then click on area and there will be list of websites and then user choose website and will see info about related computers.

For now my code looks like:

File app.component.html:

```
     <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Area</th>
        <th>AD_Site_Name</th>
        <th>Netbios_Name</th>
        <th>UserName</th>
        <th>ARPProductName</th>
        <th>FilePath</th>
        <th>InstalledSource</th>
        <th>LastHWScan</th>
        <th>LastScanDate</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody *ngFor="let country of country">
    <tr>
      <td>{{ country.Country }}</td>
      <td>{{ country.Area }}</td>
      <td>{{ country.AD_Site_Name }}</td>
      <td>{{ country.Netbios_Name }}</td>
      <td>{{ country.UserName }}</td>
      <td>{{ country.ARPProductName }}</td>
      <td>{{ country.FilePath }}</td>
      <td>{{ country.InstalledSource }}</td>
      <td>{{ country.LastHWScan }}</td>
      <td>{{ country.LastScanDate }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

File app.component.ts:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService} from './http.service';
import { Country } from './country';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [HttpService]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit { 

  country: Country[]=[];
  area: Country[]=[];

  constructor(private httpService: HttpService){}

  ngOnInit(){

      this.httpService.getData().subscribe(data => this.country=data["countryList"]);
  }

}
```

File http.service.ts:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService{

    constructor(private http: HttpClient){ }

    getData(){
        return this.http.get('/assets/data.json')
    }
}
```

File country.ts:

```
export class Country{
    Country: string;
    Area: string;
    AD_Site_Name: string;
    Netbios_Name: string;
    UserName: string;
    ARPProductName: string;
    FilePath: string;
    InstalledSource: string;
    LastHWScan: string;
    LastScanDate: string;
}
```

How to create these collapsed rows?

Comment: You can use PrimeNG Tree Table Component. https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/treetable

Comment: Thank you for the idea :) But then I need to change my data structure to this children sections somehow. Do you know how can I do it?)